# Jsoup: get data from table

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I would like to get `71–85` from a web page using Jsoup. After some trial-and-error, I was able to do it by using the following code:

```
document.select("#row_13 > div.row-desc > div").text();
```

I don't think this is a good solution, thought. I'm using here `id` which is a part of a table.  A better approach would be perhaps to get what appears after `Pages`. However, I have no clue whatsoever how to approach this. Any help would be much welcome!

```
<div style="" class="  row row-even" id="row_13">
   <div class="row-label" >
      <div class="white_label ">Pages</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row-desc">
      <div class="white_desc " style="width: 100%">
         71–85
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDI**
Here's the page the above content is taken from:
http://cejsh.icm.edu.pl/cejsh/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-dc6b14c1-8478-426a-8f2e-bb5636e0a5e9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A better approach would be perhaps to get what appears after `Pages`.

First, select the element with class `row-label` that contains text "Pages".
Then, select the first sibling of that element and fetch its text.

You can do so like this:

```
document.select(".row-label:contains(Pages) + *").first().text();
```

You can even omit `.first()` if you know for a fact there's only one element with class `row-label` that contains the text "Pages":

```
document.select(".row-label:contains(Pages) + *").text();
```

Refer to the [`Selector`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) syntax for info on notation used.